# block all Torrent traffic via dansguardian

Tags: bittorrent, traffic

i was wondering how to block all Torrent traffic via dansguardian

Comment: @Alvar It's a web [content filter](http://dansguardian.org/?page=whatisdg).

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is to block Torrents, then I suggest that you use [UFW](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW).  Its Ubuntu default Firewall.  To make it easier, you can install the UFW GUI, [GUFW](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Gufw).  To enable the GUI, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install
```

Once done, search for firewall in dash, when it opens, click on Unlock, and then click on Edit, and choose Add Rule.

[image]

When that window opens, add the rule that matches your situation.  See image below.

[image]